# Why does a voltage buffer has an high input impedance?

Tags: voltage, amplifier

When considering great voltage gains in amplifiers, a high input impedance is the main rule, followed by a low output impedance. But then, if we look at common-collector circuit (BJT), it has no voltage gain, and still, it has the highest input impedance.

I understand the calculations that get us to the input and output impedances, what I don't get, is how does this respect the ideal voltage gain amplifiers principles?

Comment: Common Collector amplifies current at unity voltage gain , which in turn amplifies emitter load impedance to base.both by hFE  Whereas Common emitter relies on low emitter impedance so input impedance is a tradeoff with voltage gain.   The current gain is used to create a voltage gain as a ratio of  the collector load to emitter impedance ratio.

Comment: *"Why does a voltage buffer has an high input impedance?"* - an ideal voltage buffer has, by definition, infinite input impedance, zero output impedance and a voltage gain of 1 independent of frequency.  A common-collector amplifier has high input impedance, low output impedance, an open-circuit voltage gain just less than 1 and relatively large bandwidth.  Perhaps I don't understand your question but what do you mean by *"how does this respect the ideal voltage gain amplifiers principles..."*?

Comment: Please make your mind up - are you talking about a voltage buffer (as defined by Alfred) or are you talking about a voltage amplifier (which has no set rule for input impedance). Even if there were rules for voltage amplifiers, a high input impedance wouldn't be top of the list. VTC (as unclear) because there are too many incorrect presumptions in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably assume, like many beginners, that the only "useful" amplification is voltage amplification, since that is what is taught first (usually).

The CC configuration, more commonly known as *emitter follower* is an example of an amplifier that doesn't provide voltage gain, but current gain instead, hence also power gain. It is also known as (voltage) *buffer* (amplifier).

BTW, that's the same principle used for buffer gates in digital logic: they are useless from a strict logic POV, since the logic level at their input is the same as the one at the output. Their role is purely electric: they provide current gain (and delay).

Keep in mind that electronics is a complex subject: it is nearly impossible to reduce all its complexity to a bunch of basic ideal circuits. Of course you cannot dump tons of stuff on a beginner, so they teach the basics, and this tends to hide much of that complexity ("amplification is only voltage amplification" is one of that "lie to children things").

Comment: "The CC configuration, more commonly known as emitter follower is an example of a current amplifier, also called buffer".  This surprising statement leads to the question: Which quantity is "buffered" -  current or voltage? And - when the emitter voltage follows the base voltage, which quantity acts as an input signal? See Alfred Centauri`s comment. I rather think, a CURRENT AMPLIFIER has - by definition and by design - a LOW input resistance.

Comment: @LvW Well, that's just the usual terminology. If you argue about why they call "buffer" something that amplifies current, I don't know (I never heard someone calling "buffer" an amplifier circuit providing voltage gain, at least not as a specific term). As for the "ideal principles" cited by the OP, I assumed he stuck with the idea that the only "ideal" amps are "voltage amps", so they *must* have voltage gain (possibly infinite, like ideal op amps).

Comment: Lorenzo Donati: "I never heard someone calling "buffer" an amplifier circuit providing voltage gain". And what about an opamp wired as a "unity-gain buffer"? Does it amplify current? To me, the terminology is clear: An "ideal" voltage amplifier (example: opamp) has an infinite input impedance and an ideal current amplifier (example: NORTON amplifier) has zero input impedance. A current-feedback amplifier (like AD844) provides both and can be used in both modes. (By the way: Regarding the working principle, the BJT is, of course, a transconductance device.)

Comment: @LvW Sorry, but I don't understand your objection. An op-amp  unity (voltage) gain buffer is, by definition, an amplifier which doesn't amplify voltage, so it just amplify current, i.e. a low(er) impedance load can be driven with a replica of the source voltage, hence we have current gain. Moreover what you call an "ideal" voltage amplifier is an ideal op-amp (infinite gain), which is intended to be used in a feedback loop. An ideal (voltage) amplifier, to me, is a device which has infinite input impedance, zero output impedance and *constant finite* gain over an infinite bandwidth.

Comment: @LvW Rereading your first comment, maybe I can understand the misunderstanding: are you objecting to my use of the term "current amplifier", perhaps? In that context I meant an amplifier which does have current gain greater than unity (and still has unity voltage gain).

Comment: Lorenzo Donati, I am involved in analog electronics since more that 45 years - however, I must admit that I do not know any knowledge source (textbook, etc.) stating that "an op-amp unity (voltage) gain buffer is, by definition, an amplifier which doesn't amplify voltage, so it just amplify current". To me a current amplifier is an active device with current-in and current-out. A unity-gain voltage buffer is nothing else than a voltage amplifier having a gain of "1". Following your terminology, also Alfred Centauri`s comment would be wrong. What is your answer?

Comment: @LvW I see now that indeed you are objecting to my, admittedly sloppy, use of the term "current amplifier" (which I hastily used to mean "providing current gain"). I'll edit my answer to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation showing the difference of a 1kHz sin wave source with 1V amplitude and 2.7V offset and 1kΩ impedance into a 1kΩ load with and without a buffer.

[image]

Notice that even with a gain of 1, the buffered signal is almost double the unbuffered signal. This is one reason to use a buffer.

[image]